# NVidia Cuda, результат возвращает cudaErrorInitializationError, как решить проблему с запуском?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

Проблема заключается в том, что после вызова cudaSetDevice(0) результатом (cudaError_t) возвращает cudaErrorInitializationError - как это исправить?

Как мне кажется причиной проблемы мог возникнут, из за того, что у меня на дискретной видеокарте имеется CUDA 2.1 (Характеристики выложил в скрин) Nvidia ToolKit установлена новейшее.

[image: CUDA v2.1]

---

Я нашел ответ тут: [stackoverflow.com/questions/30693704/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693704/no-cuda-capable-device-is-detected-with-cuda-capable-gpu-installed-win7)

Comment: Дайте нормальный заголовок вопросу [ask]

Comment: Я нашел ответ тут. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693704/no-cuda-capable-device-is-detected-with-cuda-capable-gpu-installed-win7 Спасибо за просмотры :(

Comment: Вы можете дать ответ на собственный вопрос с помощью кнопки ниже